# Can we change request in links in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way that I can, in Laravel 4.2, make a url link such that it sends a DELETE or PUT request?

For example, I have a delete button, I know I could put it in a form and make the form send a delete request to resource.destroy to delete something and all that. What I want is to avoid having o wrap the button in a form, and just make a url that goes to resource.destroy (I'm using restful resources) and does what's in that function. I know I can use action() but that sends a GET request. Can I make it send a DELETE/PUT whatever other request without wrapping it in a form? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to send a anything else that a GET request using a "normal" HTML link.
You either have to wrap the button in a form or use javascript. Here's a simple example with jQuery:

#### The link with generated url

```
<a id="button" href="{{ route('route.name') }}">Click me</a>
```

or use the laravel helper for the full link

```
{{ link_to_route('route.name', 'Click me', array(), array('id' => 'button')) }}
```

(Actually it doesn't matter how you generate the link as long as the `href` attribute contains the right url)

#### jQuery event listener

Then you can listen to the `click` event, read the `href` attribute and use it for the ajax request

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid redirect from clicking on the link
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).prop('href'),
        type: 'PUT'
    });
});
```

*Note that this way the user stays on the same page. Depending on what exactly you want to do, you might want to do a redirect after the ajax call*

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @lukasgeiter's answer, another option is to use the little Restfulizer.js "library" that is floating around the web in a few places. Ryan Durham made some updates to it for his Sentinel package, so that's the one I would start off with: [restfulizer.js](https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel/blob/master/public/js/restfulizer.js)

Using this library, you just add a `data-method` attribute to the link, and set it to the method you want to use.  It uses unobtrusive javascript to create a hidden form with the correct inputs, and submits the hidden form when the link is clicked.  You can also set a `data-token` attribute if you need a CSRF token, and set a class of "action_confirm" if you want a confirm box to pop up (the CSRF token and confirm box are part of Ryan's updates).

Full use example:

```
<a href="post/1" data-method="delete" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" class="action_confirm">Delete Me</a>
```

A more extreme option would be to include the rails [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) library (works fine with Laravel), and read the documentation on how to get that working. It would provide a bit more flexibility, but has a higher setup/learning curve.